# Pynamodb - how to set the region?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

Python 3

The code below works but saves to the us-east-1 region.  How would I make it save to us-west-1? I have dug through the source of Pynamodb but not found the right way to do it.

```
from pynamodb.models import Model
from pynamodb.indexes import GlobalSecondaryIndex, AllProjection
from pynamodb.attributes import UnicodeAttribute, NumberAttribute

class DaysIndex(GlobalSecondaryIndex):
    """
    This class represents a global secondary index
    """
    read_capacity_units = 2
    write_capacity_units = 1
    projection = AllProjection()
    days_old = NumberAttribute(hash_key=True)


class HackerNewsLinks(Model):
    """
    A test model that uses a global secondary index
    """
    table_name = 'HackerNews'
    link = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    title = UnicodeAttribute()
    days_index = DaysIndex()
    days_old = NumberAttribute(default=0)

if not HackerNewsLinks.exists():
    HackerNewsLinks.create_table(read_capacity_units=1, write_capacity_units=1, region='us-west-1')

hn_item = HackerNewsLinks('http://www.blah.com', title='forum_subject', days_old=10)
hn_item.save()

# Indexes can be queried easily using the index's hash key
for item in HackerNewsLinks.days_index.query(1):
    print("Item queried from index: {0}".format(item))
```

Comment: can you please check andwer to this question it might help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101195/amazon-dynamodb-region-specific-connection

Comment: @HarshalBulsara this is Pynamodb not boto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just added region support to the PynamoDB models API in version 0.1.12, would you mind upgrading and trying again?

Here is the syntax:

```
class HackerNewsLinks(Model):
    """
    A test model that uses a global secondary index
    """
    class Meta:
        region = 'us-west-1'
        table_name = 'HackerNews'
    link = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    title = UnicodeAttribute()
    days_index = DaysIndex()
    days_old = NumberAttribute(default=0)
```